# Upload file without saving it

Tags: drupal-7

I'd like to upload a file and parse it, without saving it permanently. 
How would I get the contents of the uploaded file in my submit handler? The only things I could find always saved the file it seems.

Comment: it's not possible in your scenario to save the file then just delete it?

Comment: it is, but it seems a waste of time... is file_save_upload the way to go then?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to save it anyways: When the file gets uploaded via PHP-form, it always gets written on a disk. Luckely for you drupal's "managed_file"-form element treats all files as non-permanent -> cron will get rid of them in time if you don't add 'file_usage_add'. This means you don't have to delete them.

Long story short:

```
function my_form($form,&$form_state) {
    $form["myfile"]= array(
        '#type'   => "managed_file",    
        '#progress_indicator' => "bar",
        '#upload_location'    => "public://",           
        '#upload_validators' => array(
            'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),                        
        ),  
    );       
}

function my_form_submit($form,&$form_state) {
    $file = file_load($form_state["values"]["myfile"]);

    //Do what you want with it. 
    //Keep in mind that the file will be gone soon automatically. 
}
```

Another way would be to [read the file via Javascript](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html) and pass the results to PHP via POST. Then the file would not get "written" anywhere.